# Name or method not found during function call in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I'm just getting started with VBA. I have this Subprocess which erases a given Sheet for me without displaying an error message. However, the procecss is halted with an error in the eraseSheet call.. It says that name or method don't exist. I can't figure out where? `wb` is a workbook (as defined above). `name_imported_sheet` is defined as a string. Where is there a name or method that doesn't fit?

```
Sub eraseSheet(ByRef sheet As Worksheet)
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    sheet.Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub

Sub mainSub()

Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook

...

If sheetExists(name_imported_sheet) Then
    
    eraseSheet (wb.Sheets(name_imported_sheet))
    
End If

...

End Sub
```

Also is there a way to get more precise interpreter warnings?

Comment: It should be `eraseSheet wb.Sheets(name_imported_sheet)` not `eraseSheet (wb.Sheets(name_imported_sheet))`

Comment: Sheet ≠ Worksheet and you try to push a sheet into a worksheet variable `ByRef sheet As Worksheet`. Change all `Sheets` into `Worksheets`. • Sheets can contain charts and worksheets etc.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ How would I take a Sheet then as an argument? There's no Sheet type per se is there?

Comment: @glades no there is no type `sheet`. But as long as you have only worksheets and no chart sheets or anything else you can stick to `As Worksheets` and use `Worksheets` instead of `Sheets`. As it is now `eraseSheet` can only delete sheets of type worksheets anyway. So the name `eraseSheet` is missleading and should be `eraseWorksheet`. If you really plan to delete other types of sheets with this function too then you can define `ByRef sheet As Object` but note that you can then push any object into this functions not only sheets. So you can also push a range in there and it will delete it.